# What kind of world map and type of game is shown in these images of ARK?

Tags: mods, ark-survival-evolved

I'm interested to know what kind of world map and in general what type of game or mods is playing in the images that I will show here below.

Mi first impression is that in the images we can see he is playing [The Island](http://ark.gamepedia.com/The_Island) world map, because as you will see it is a world map with much forestation, however, he has a [Mantis](http://ark.gamepedia.com/Mantis), and a golem (a kind of criature that I seen on a dungeon, it is not a giant [Rock Elemental](http://ark.gamepedia.com/Rock_Elemental), this one is smaller). The problem is that those enemies theorically will only appear on the [Scorched Earth](http://ark.gamepedia.com/Scorched_Earth) world map that is part of the [ARK's expansion](http://store.steampowered.com/app/512540/?l=spanish) ...and that is a desertic canyon world map, then, how it is possibly that he is playing other map with the same creatures?.

You can see more videos of this person in his youtube channel:

https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCggHFGmLDDStxyM-uy9DYnQ/videos

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it not possible to ask the video creator?

Comment: @Frank He is a very known youtuber in my country, probably he will not or have not time to answer these questions. I could have much more luck asking on a community which is oriented to video games, than publishing a question/comment on a Youtube video messing with other thousands of comments from his followers... PS: do you really think that this question deserves a downvote for that reason?. Thanks for comment!

Comment: Seeing as how this seems like basic info to at least try to get, or be in the description for the video, yeah, that does deserve a downvote.

Comment: You're prejudging. I already tried yo publish a question many times in his videos (of course without a response from him or from any of him followers) and of course in the video description does not specify these things. Reasons for what I'm asking here, a question for ARK experienced players like you.

Comment: No, I'm judging based on the information you have provided.  Nowhere in the question do you mention that you've tried to ask for this information before, or that it doesn't exist in the description.  Heck, there's not even a link to the video so we can go look ourselves.

Comment: @Frank ok, I'm sorry for the misunderstanding. You know that if I share a link to the video this could be downvoted and voted to be closed for spam reasons, however I would like to share it then you can see all his videos to determine what type of game he is playing, I could share it?.

Comment: @ElektroStudios That seems unlikely. It is directly relevant to the question.

Comment: Ok guys I've updated the question with the url to him channel, Thanks both for comment. EDIT: Oh, and the video from which I took the screenshots is this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=saHyVFfIXIo&t=625s

Comment: I also tried to find the server he is playing to know the map and to ask directlly the Admin for the mods used because I see much things unclear, I mean how he can play those golem and mantis criatures in a non-Scorched Earth world map, however I didn't found the server. This youtuber never gives that kind of info in his videos. The only thing I have clear is that he plays with the Capitalism mods set: https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=770607491 and seems he plays Pirate World total conversion mod: https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=547377246

Answer (score 1):

The map appears to be the default The Island as you have mentioned. Your first image looks to be a bay in the southeast, commonly known as [Drayo's Cove](http://ark.gamepedia.com/Drayo%27s_Cove).

The Mantis also appears to be the one from [Scorched Earth](http://ark.gamepedia.com/Scorched_Earth). They can be brought to the island. Relevant quote regarding this below.

> Scorched Earth adds 11 new creatures, over 50 new items, a new boss, and a whole new map.
>
> **Creatures tamed and items recieved can be brought to the vanilla island** and used by people with and without the expansion.

The transfer of players and tamed animals between servers/islands is done using [Obelisks](http://ark.gamepedia.com/Obelisk).